# Can't get switch function to work to get into a different static class

Tags: c#, console, switch-statement

I'm pretty new to C#, and programming overall. I'm doing a homework assignment right now and I'm losing my mind because I can't wrap my head around what my error here is. I feel like it's got to be something so obvious but I just can't see it. The errors are **"ProgramBase.Menu()"**, **"The name 'Console'does not exist in the current context"**, **"QuestionRectangle does not exist in the current context"**.

```
using System;

namespace ProgLab3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool displayMenu = true;
        while (displayMenu)
        {
            displayMenu = Menu();
        }
    }

    private static bool Menu()
    {


        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the menu! Below are your choices of options.");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 1 to open Areas of Rectangles\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 2 to open Biggest Number\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 3 to open Valid Points\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 4 to open Dollar Game\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 5 to open Oldest Person\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 6 to open Hi Lo Game\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 7 to quit\n");

        switch (Console.ReadLine())
        {
            case "1":
                QuestionRectangle();
                return true;
            case "2":

                return true;
            case "3":
                return false;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }


    private static void QuestionRectangle()
    {
        {
            double width1, length1, area1;
            double width2, length2, area2;

            // Asking the user for measurements and then saving those numbers onto variables for the FIRST rectangle
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Areas of Rectangles choice.\nPlease start off by inputting the width of your first rectangle, do not include the metric unit of measurement.");
            width1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Now please input the length of the first rectangle.");
            length1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            //Calculating the area of the FIRST rectangle
            area1 = width1 * length1;

            // Asking the user for measurements and then saving those numbers onto variables for the SECOND rectangle
            Console.WriteLine("Alright great, now please input the width of your second rectangle.");
            width2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Now what is the length of your second rectangle?");
            length2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            //Calculating the area of the SECOND rectangle
            area2 = width2 * length2;

            // Checks if area 1 is greater than area 2
            if (area1 > area2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your first rectangle has a greater area, that area being " + area1);
            }

            // Checks if area 2 is greater than area 1
            if (area1 < area2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your second rectangle has a greater area, that area being " + area2);
            }

            // Checks if the areas are equal to each other
            if (area1 == area2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your rectangles have the same area, that area being " + area1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: _There's more but I don't see why I would need to include the rest of this program_ - you need to include the parts that don’t work as the code in your question compiles and runs 

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hWvI3Z

Comment: You don't need to put **EDITED** into the title. It's useless noise. The site tracks the revision history of every question and answer posted here. Please do not add irrelevant information to your post content, whether it's in the title or body of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that `Console`/`QuestionRectangle` is not reachable in the current context. This can mean one or more of the following:

- you have a typo
- the resource is not defined in the current namespace
- the resource exists in another namespace which is not included using the `using` keyword

So, you will need to check your namespaces and fix the problems you have accordingly. I can see that `QuestionRectangle` is defined in your code, so I suppose that the actual code you have is either different, or has the problem at a place which was not shared.

EDIT

It turns out that in this particular case the copied content was corrupted along the way. carsonSgit looked into the issue and was able to localize what was missing. From then point on it was easier for him/her to find the path to the solution, by ensuring that the source and the target is identical.

Comment: I just edited it and added in the code that I had not included. I don't think that the issue would be in the newly added code because it runs properly when I run it in its own program, and then I copy-pasted it under the menu. Is it possible that copy-pasting it into the code was a mistake? As I didn't do anything to the namespace of the program, I only kept the one from the Menu.

I'm using Visual Studio, to my knowledge if the text is the right colour and doesn't have any red underline, it isn't a typo. I didn't put "using" anywhere and haven't learned how to, so how would I use it?

Comment: @carsonSgit red underlines indicate syntax errors. Typos are often causing syntax errors, but not always. If your typo is an alphanumeric deviation of a name, resulting in a name that was not defined, then it's not a syntax error. If you check whether the name being used matches the defined resource in every corresponding letter, then you can exclude the possibility of a typo. If so, then it's a namespace problem. Fortunately you can easily find the exact line where the error occurs. You could hep us to help you by editing the question and showing the exact line where the error happened.

Comment: @carsonSgit there are no technical problems in copy-pasting code from one project to the other. In general it is wise to avoid copy-pasting whenever possible, a reusable resource accross projects looks like a library and it would be wise to convert it into one for easier maintenance. Putting this aside, if you copy-paste code which worked in project1 but not in project2 due to missing resources, then you either did not attach a resource to the project, or did not add a using statement.

Comment: @carsonSgit which namespace and class is QuestionRectangle belonging to and can you show the line which complains about it? It's difficult to comment a code that was not shared.

Comment: After looking more into namespaces due to what you said, I fiddled around with them and tried to find the problem. It turns out, the file in my repository linked to the code had corrupted along the way and was missing data making the entire program unable to function. Which goes along with all the things you suggested. I've fixed my storage and put the code into a new file and it works now. Thank you so much for all the help and all of the new information! I appreciate it a lot and I hope you have a great day!